# @Value for Injected Application Properties

Tags: java, spring, heroku, spring-boot

I have the following in my `application.properties`;

```
spring.datasource.username=${USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
...
twitter.consumer.key=${CONSUMER_KEY}
twitter.consumer.secret=${CONSUMER_SECRET}
twitter.access.key=${ACCESS_KEY}
twitter.access.secret=${ACCESS_SECRET}
```

The top three properties are set by the environment when the application is pushed up to a heroku instance. The values that get set by the environment are then used to make connections to the database specific to that environment. This is all good.

The problem is with the last four. As these are sensitive information I need them to be injected by the environment also. I have then used autowiring to add these to a spring boot component.

```
@Value("${twitter.consumer.key}")
private String consumerKey;
@Value("${twitter.consumer.secret}")
private String consumerSecret;
@Value("${twitter.access.key}")
private String accessKey;
@Value("${twitter.access.secret}")
private String accessSecret;
```

Now, when I build the application it complains of being unable to resolve the `ACCESS_KEY` etc because I do not have these environment variables on my local machine.

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'CONSUMER_KEY' in string value "${CONSUMER_KEY}"
```

How can I build the application without explicitly setting these values? Is there, for example, some way of setting defaults for the application properties if they cannot be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the build from failing you can specify default values for the application properties if the key could not be resolved. For example;

```
twitter.consumer.key=${CONSUMER_KEY:fallback}
twitter.consumer.secret=${CONSUMER_SECRET:fallback}
twitter.access.key=${ACCESS_KEY:fallback}
twitter.access.secret=${ACCESS_SECRET:fallback}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the @Value annotiation it is possible to set a default value:

```
@Value("${my.property:default}")
```